# How do I change the style of an element inside a <div /> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an index.html like so:

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  Text inside div
  <h1>
    Header inside div
  </h1>
</div>

<h1>
  Header outside div
</h1>
```

And my style.css looks like this:

```css
#mydiv h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

To change the color of "Text inside div" with JS, I can do this:

```js
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.color = "red";
```

But how do I change the color of "Header inside div" using only JS? (without modifying the HTML or CSS or changing h1 outside the div)

Comment: The best way to do this would be to change the class of that element through Javascript and define the class in the CSS. You shouldn't be putting colors in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `document.querySelector`, you can select `h1` tag inside `#mydiv` selector.

```js
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.color = "red";

document.querySelector("#mydiv h1").style.color = "yellow";
```

```css
#mydiv h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  Text inside div
  <h1>
    Header inside div
  </h1>
</div>

<h1>
  Header outside div
</h1>
```

Comment: The querySelector did not work for me then I realized I was forgetting the # sign in front of my ID.
It worked perfectly later. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

`document.querySelector('#mydiv h1').style.color = "green";`

This will select the h1 element inside the div.

Using `document.querySelector` is really powerful and makes manipulations like this easy. Check out the [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)